# $scope doesn't picks up string from form input - AngularJS, JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angularjs-scope

I am trying to implement Change Password feature in MVC (Rest server) application from the User Control Panel but because of some strange reason I can't scope values from form input.

My html form:

```
<accordion-group heading="Change password" is-open="changePasswordStatus.open" style="cursor: pointer">
    <div>
        <div>
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <form-row model="newPassword" name="New: " size="col-sm-8"></form-row>
                <form-row model="repeatedNewPassword" name="Repeat: " size="col-sm-8"></form-row>
                <form-row model="currentPassword" name="Current: " size="col-sm-8"></form-row>
                <br>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="changePassword()">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" ng-click="changePasswordStatus.open = !changePasswordStatus.open">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
</accordion-group>
```

My formRow.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputText3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{name}}</label>
    <div class="{{size}}">
        <input type="{{type}}" class="form-control" data-ng-model="model">
    </div>
</div>
```

My formRow.js:

```
collectionsApp.directive('formRow', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            name: '@',
            size: '@',
            type: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: '/directives/formRow.html',
        link: function(scope, attrs, element) {

        }
    }
});
```

My userController:

```
$scope.changePassword = function() {
    if ($scope.newPassword === $scope.repeatedNewPassword) {
        userService.changePassword($scope.newPassword, $scope.currentPassword);
    } else {
            $scope.alerts.push({
                msg : 'Passwords do not match!'
            })
    }
}
```

And when I enter values in inputs and place breakpoints and trigger changePassword() in debug i get:
[image]

If condition has passed with value of true because they are both undefined.

Comment: what version of Angular ?

Comment: angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js

Comment: did you happen to get this working?

Comment: I have just arrived at my internship company this morning... :) I have managed to scope data you said (i have created object with 3 fields and in html i made model="object.field", and in controller i call userService.changePassword($scope.password.new, $scope.password.current), and in debug mode I can see that userService is trying to hit '/user/changePasword' with input values loaded in new, and current but in console I get "cannot read property protocol of undefined". It never sends request to my rest controller.

Comment: @PapiTheTypecaster if this the same or even a new issue, I would recommend putting a plunker together to help triage the issue, but at a quick glance I am wondering if your service is missing some property.  Though when angular 2.0 comes they will be making a lot of breaking changes, I recommend using the $resource service if you aren't already for REST calls.

Comment: I have asked new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548611/userservic-wont-pass-data-to-back-end-cannot-read-property-protocol-of-undef - few minutes ago, and I will reconsider setting up a plunker if that will be needed. I will study your suggestion about $resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this may be the case of [prototypical inheritance and scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes), requiring an object being passed into your scoped parameters.  Mind trying to change your parent scope to use an object and bind to the properties and not the primitive values:

```
$scope.security = {newPassword : '', currentPassword = ''};
```

then you would use something like this in your attributes:

```
model="security.newPassword"
```

Or better yet, not make it confusing with model:

```
myapp-model="security.newPassword"
```

or pass in the whole object

```
myapp-security="security"
```

Answer (score 1):

Working in this [plunker template](http://plnkr.co/edit/X3ve2b?p=preview) ?

```
<form ...>
  <form-row model="newPassword" name="New: " size="col-sm-8" required ></form-row>
  <form-row model="repeatedNewPassword" name="Repeat: " size="col-sm-8" required ></form-row>
  <form-row model="currentPassword" name="Current: " size="col-sm-8" required ></form-row>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure? ng-model (data-ng-model) is already bonded to model. Take  a look at FormRow directive again please... Can you elaborate why you suggest this?

Comment: @PapiTheTypecaster you're right it doesn't need ng-model.